# Java: Accepting self-signed certificates

Tags: java, security, certificate, self-signed

I use the following TrustManager to accept self-signed certificates from my local test server in my Java application:

```
public class CertificateAcceptor {

    private TrustManager[] createTrustManager() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // leave blank to trust every client
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // leave blank to trust every client
            }
        }};
        return trustAllCerts;
    }
```

I have some security concerns with that, since as far as I know, this accepts just all certificates. So I'm asking myself if there is a way to only accept certificates that are coming from localhost on Port 9443?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that these are *your* self-signed certificates and not just any self-signed certificates, it would probably make better sense to create your own certificate authority so you can have valid, signed certificates instead of creating work arounds and losing the benefits of have certificates.

By creating your own CA you can sign your own certificates and then simply import the CA certificate into your Java keystore. Then no more problems with self-signed certs. Plus you have the added benefit of being able to trust the certificate (assuming you take good care of your certificate keys).

Being your own CA is actually much easier than you might think. At least that was the case for me.

Here is a link with some step-by-step instructions. 
http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/howto.ca.html

Comment: Thanks. But it's not only my self-signed certificate I want to accept.

Comment: Well, then I would guess that you can look at REMOTE_ADDR in CGI variables and stop processing if it is != 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ok. But I can´t see a way to retrieve this from a certificate?

Comment: You would nto receive it fromt he certificate, you would receive it fromt he request made to the application.

Comment: Wait, do you mean you only want to accept a cert that is bound to localhost:9443?

Comment: You should be able to call getSubjectDN().getName() on the certificate (which will be one of the values in the X509Certificate array. For a cert bound to "localhost" it should return "localhost". I think. Never tried. Certs are connected with an IP and port at the web server, so that info is not in the cert itself.

Comment: This returns the name of the application in my case. But I found a way that I´m not sure if it is valid. I asked another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739951/is-this-a-valid-approach-to-accept-self-signed-certificates) to avoid confusion here.